# a search for answers tonight

Tags: sentence-construction

A CNN news report begins with the following:

> **a search** for answers tonight after an unthinkable crime Friday in Newport News, Virginia. Police say a first grader shot a teacher on purpose after an altercation.

I'm wondering what is being omitted before "a search." Is it "This is" or "There is"?

Comment: _There is a search_ or _a search is going on_. To use _this_ would imply that the report itself is the search, which it isn't.

Comment: Could "This a search for..." be an invitation to the audience to find out about the news story that is going to unfold?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than saying "There is a fire..." or "There was a fire...", they simply start in with "A fire".

It's normally incorrect grammar, but this is part of TV news' version of [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese).

You could also interpret it as the title of the story, rather than a sentence. Regardless, it's only used at the beginning of a report.